# Problem: Attribute with the same code already exists

Tags: admin, migration, magento-1-2-migration

I used **data-migration-tool** to migrate my store from **1.9.2.2 to 2.1.14**, but after the **migration**, I find I can't open "edit" page of any existing product. The following error message show up:

========================================================

> There has been an error processing your request.
>
> The configuration parameter "formElement" is a required for "" field.
>
> Error log record number: 1495859023951

(Yes, there is nothing in the second quote mark)

========================================================

Also, I tried to **add new product**, with new attribute set, but when I configured it and click **"save"**, it shows:

========================================================

> Attribute with the same code already exists.

========================================================

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

**YOU NEED TO MANUALLY ASSIGN EXTRA ATTRIBUTES IN DEFAULT ATTRIBUTE SET AFTER MIGRATE IN MAGENTO2.1.14**

> After Migration Magento2.1.14 created extra Attribute set **Migration_Default**
>   For example I have an attribute **someinfo** in Magento1.9.2.2 But after migration you need to go **Default attribute set** OF Magento2.1.14 and need assign manually attribute  **someinfo** and other all

[image]

[image]

Comment: I try to assign attributes to default attribute set, but I still can't save. The error message is : Attribute with the same code already exists.

Comment: You need to set attributes in default attribute set

Comment: I am setting attributes in default attribute set. You can see the screen capture here: http://oi65.tinypic.com/2upwv7m.jpg